# eclipselink : NullPointerException thrown from org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.lock

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

On trying to get PESSIMISTIC_READ lock on a database row under heavy load, sometimes ends up getting NPE.

```
EntityManager em = SMEntityManagerFactory.getEM(); 
AccountDao accountDao = new AccountDao(em); 
AccountEntity entity = accountDao.findEntityByName(this.getUserName(),this.getUserDomain()); 
em.lock(entity, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ);

Errors:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.executeQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:920)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.lock(EntityManagerImpl.java:1903)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.lock(EntityManagerImpl.java:1846)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2006.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: Code:

EntityManager em = SMEntityManagerFactory.getEM();
AccountDao accountDao = new AccountDao(em);
AccountEntity entity = accountDao.findEntityByName(this.getUserName(), this.getUserDomain());
em.lock(entity, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_READ);

Comment: what does SMEntityManagerFactory.getEM() do exactly? Hopefully it is just an EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager call.